# On intervals chosen randomly within the unit circle.

Tags: probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry, bivariate-distributions

> Let $S = \{(x,y)\in R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ be the unit circle in $R^2$. Let $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2)$ be independent, both having uniform distribution over $S$. Let $D$ denote the Euclidean distance between $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$. Show that $E(D^2) = 1$.

I think that $f_{X_1,Y_1}(x_1,y_1)= \dfrac{1}{2\pi},\text{if}\,\,(x_1,y_1)\in S$ and $D^2= (X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2$. Then I can't proceed.

Comment: Have you tried using FOIL on $D^2$ followed by an appeal to the _linearity_ of expectation? Do you have any reason to believe that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables and thus $E[X_1X_2] = E[X_1]E[X_2]$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think since $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2)$ are independent so $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. But I don't understand what do you mean by FOIL on $D^2$.

Comment: A.D. FOIL (first-outer-inner-last) is a mnemonic much beloved by American middle-school students as a reminder of $$(a+b)(c+d)= ac + ad + bc + bd.$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate So I need to find $E(X_1)$ and $E(X_1^2)$. But how can I find these values.

Comment: Can you find the _marginal_ distribution of $f_X(x)$ of $X$ from the _joint_ distribution? Or you can apply $$E[X^i] = \int\int x^i  f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy \mathrm dx$$ where the inner integral effectively computes $f_X(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOILing results in
$$E[D^2]=E[X_1^2]+E[X_2^2]+E[Y_1^2]+E[Y^2]-2E[X_1X_2]-2E[Y_1Y_2]=4E[X_1^2]=1,$$
where I used the following obvious looking facts which will have to be verified later:

1. $E[X_1]=E[X_2]=E[Y_1]=E[Y_2]=0.$
2. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and so are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
3. Less obvious is that $E[X_1^2]=E[X_1^2]=E[X_1^2]=E[X_1^2]=\frac{1}{4}.$

---

The pairs $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ are independent by definition. However, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are not independent for the same $i$. Their joint distribution is defined such that for a measurable set of $A\subset \mathbb R^2$
$$P((X_i,Y_i)\in A)=\frac{1}{\pi}\lambda(A\cap C),$$
where $C$ is the unit disc centered at $(0,0)$ and $\lambda $ is the (Lebesgue) measure of area in $\mathbb R^2$.

---

In order to prove 1. and 3. we need the pdf of, say, $X_1$. I hope that, based on symmetry reasons, there is no need to prove that the distribution of the four random variables, we have here, are the same.

By definition

$$f_{X_1}(x)=\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(x\le X_1<x+\Delta)}{\Delta}.$$
Notice that 
$$P(x\le X_1<x+\Delta)=P((X_1,Y_1)\in T_{\Delta,x}),$$
where
$$T_{\Delta,x}=\{(u,v):x\le u<x+\Delta, -\sqrt{1-u^2}\le v \le \sqrt{1-u^2}\}$$

In the figure below $T_{\Delta,x}$ is shown in red:
[image]

Considering the definition of the joint distribution of $(X_1,Y_2)$ we have an approximation for  the probability that

$$P(x\le X_1<x+\Delta)=P((X_1,Y_1)\in \color {red}{T_{\Delta,x}})\approx \Delta \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

since in order for $X_1$ to fall in betwwe $x$ and $x+\Delta$ the point $(X_1,Y_1)$ has to fall in the red region. (Note that this approximation could be made absolutely precise by taking the ppropriate lower and upper bounds.)

With this the pdf of $X_1$ can be given:

$$f_{X_1}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2},& \text{ if } -1\le x \le 1\\
0,&\text {otherwise.}\end{cases}.$$

Let' check if $f_{X_1}$ is a density function. Indeed, [with the help of Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C+-1+to+1), we get:

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=1.$$

---

As far as the expectation of $X_1$ we have

$$E[X_1]=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=0,$$
as [Alpha reinforces](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C+-1+to+1).

---

Finally, the expectation of $X_1^2$ is
$$E[X_1^2]=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^1x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{8}=\frac{1}{4},$$
as [Alpha reinforces again](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C+-1+to+1).

Comment: Or, more simply, without using Alpha etc, \begin{align}E[X_1^2+Y_1^2]&=\int\int(x^2+y^2)\frac{1}{\pi}\,dx\,dy =\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi}r^2\frac{1}{2\pi}\,rd\theta\,dr\\&= 2\int_0^1r^3\,dr = 2 \left.\frac{r^4}{4}\right|_0^1=\frac 12\end{align}

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Shame on me. However, my real problem (hidden behind my solution) was the following question: How to generate a pair of random variables so that their distribution within the circle be uniform. The solution was to using two independent $U(-1,1)$ distributed rvs's and then to rejecting the result if the pair did not fall in the circle. So, I was working with conditional probabilities all the way. Then I could not switch back to the simple acceptance that such a distribution exits. Sometimes your thoughts unwillingly follow an unpleasant path.

Comment: That should have been $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r^2\frac{1}{\pi}\, rd\theta\,dr = 2\int_0^1 r^3\, dr$.